# Wierd Math with arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make an alarm with my arduino, which always activates at 0:00 and deactivates at 23:59 so the variables reset and its easier to make. Right now I want to make, that the buzzer starts after 1 minute. But the maths don't really work or I'm missing something.

**Code:**

```
/* Tutorial:
 * ---------
 * -Set the custom Variables
 * -Plug arduino at exact 0:00
 * 
 * 
 */

//Imports


//Custom Variables
int alarmMin = 1;

//Other Variables
boolean active = false;
int alarmMilli = alarmMin * 60000;

//Pins
int pBuzzer = 2;


//Start
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("-------------------------------");
  Serial.println(alarmMin);
  Serial.println(alarmMilli);
}

//Loop
void loop() {
  Serial.println(active);
  Serial.println(millis()/1000);
  Serial.println(alarmMilli/1000);
  Serial.println("-----");
  
  //If alarm-time started
  if(millis()/1000 == alarmMilli/1000){
    active = true;
  }

  //Buzzer
  if(active){
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-------------------------------
1
-5536
0
0
-5
-----
0
0
-5
-----
0
0
-5
-----
0
0
-5
-----
...
```

Why is 1*6000 = -5536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` type on an Arduino Uno is a 16-bit integer, i.e. it's range its range is from -32,768 to 327,67. Thus, 60,000 is already outside the range resulting in seemingly strange math.

Instead of `int`, use `long`. Its range is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.